# Why is my drop down list not populating with the table data?

Tags: php, database, populate

WHy is my drop down list not populating with the table data? (dropdown box is empty)
And what is used to display data upon selection of an item in that drop down - is it a "VIEW" (please do provide a study link so I can learn)

**My Code**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ismat_db");
//check connection
if(mysqli_errno($con))
{
echo "Can't Connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
echo "Connected to mySQL</br>";
}

 //$query = 'SELECT FirstName FROM persons';
//$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 'FirstName' FROM persons");

//print_r($query);

//echo '<select name="FirstName">';
echo "<select name= 'FirstName'>";
//while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
echo $row;
//echo "<option value='".$row['FirstName']."'>".'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>
```

Comment: 1. Do you get any data from the database? 2. Why aren't you printing the option text: <option value='".$row['FirstName']."'>".$row['FirstName']. '</option>'?

Comment: echo $row['FirstName']

Comment: @user4035 - just tried that line and got "FirstName" written twice...

Comment: @nevermind tried... didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had 2 errors:

I pointed the first in the comment: to print an option you must use this code:

```
echo "<option value='". $row['FirstName']."'>".$row['FirstName']
 . '</option>';
```

The second is in your SQL: you are not selecting the FirstName field from the database, but a string 'FirstName' instead. That's why it is printed twice as you said. Use this SQL to get the field:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FirstName FROM persons");
```

---

Also usually people put an id of the record and not a field, that may have possible duplicates into the value of an `<option>`. So, I would have used:

```
echo "<option value='". $row['id']."'>".$row['FirstName']
 . '</option>';
```

selecting the id from the database together with first name.

Comment: Is there a dot after persons in the $query. 
And I tried it, but got this error - mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean
And I did change the first comment - with that only it shows Firstname twice

Comment: @AbbasAnsari You can use it without any dots and quotes. I updated the answer, try now.

Comment: @AbbasAnsari Yes, there is a dot, and my query must work correctly. I suspect, that you didn't copy exactly, what I gave in the answer. Because I used backquotes and not a straight quotes, that you used.

Comment: Done - Thanks alot, Could you please explain what did this code exactly do - the <option> one? and how was I wrong..? Im new to php that is why i am learning on the way

Comment: @AbbasAnsari The `<option>` code generates options for you drop-down list. You can read about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<option value='".$row['FirstName']."'>".$row['FirstName']."</option>";
```

Also seems that you are having an issue with the database query. Swap your while loop with the following and see if it works

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['FirstName']."'>".$row['FirstName']."</option>";
    }

$result->free();
}
```

Comment: What does this do? I mean the "'>" because the drop down is not empty any more but instead of grabbing the table value under 'FirstName' Column it just says FirstName twice (Maybe twice because there are two records in the table)

Comment: It doesn't work?? The code should put the $row['FirstName'] into the options value, and also allow $row['FirstName'] to be displayed to the user in the form. With a select option, you need to set the value of the option that gets posted and also have it displayed to the user to be selected.

Comment: Put echo mysqli->error(); after your database query to see if you are getting any mysqli errors from your query.

Comment: nope doesnt display table data... I thought this was the most basic that I was trying... btw my table name is persons and has columns FirstName, LastName, Gender, Subject and Hobbies.

And its has only two record in it...could there be something wrong with my table?

Comment: Nope no error at all, I put this 

**echo mysqli_error($con);**

right after $query line.

Comment: Edited my answer to try to help you with the database query. I have not tested it.

Comment: no it didn't populate this way too but the answer below makes it happen, anyway Thanks a million for helping and giving your time - very very very much appreciated :)